# Fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^{3}\setminus \{ \mbox{2 linked circles }\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Calculate the fundamental group  of the complement in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of

$$\{ (x,y,z) \ | \ y = 0 , \ x^{2} + z^{2} = 1\} \cup \{ (x,y,z) \ | \ z = 0 , \ (x-1)^{2} + y^{2} = 1\}.$$

**Note**: this space is  $\mathbb{R}^{3}\setminus \{ \mbox{2 linked circles }\}$.

Comment: I see no question above, only an order. You should never copy/paste a question from a textbook, or phrase your question as such. Moreover, you should explain what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: @MTurgeon While I agree with your sentiments, it does seem like your tone is no different than OP's. We should lead by example.

Comment: @Sasha Ok. I see no question above, only an order. I encourage you to never copy/paste a question from a textbook, or phrase your question as such. Moreover, you should try to explain what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: One possible approach: $S^3\setminus \{\text{2 linked circles}\}$ is homotopy equivalent to a torus. Note that adding a point at $\infty$ to turn $\mathbb R^3$ into $S^3$ does not change $\pi_1$.

Comment: Look up the Wirtinger presentation.

Comment: As @JimConant says, you can add a point to make this $S^3-K$, where $K$ is your two linked circles.  This does not change the homotopy type.  Choosing another point of $S^3$ to be infinity won't change it either, so you can remove a point from $K$ to get a new (homeomorphic) space, $\mathbb{R}^3-L$, where $L$ is the union of a circle in the xy-plane, and the z-axis.  Now the deformation retraction to the torus is obvious.